# Calculating the timestamps in a pandas dataset with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataset containting IP, URL ID and timestamp columns. The IP column contains various IPs and each IP has one or multiple URL IDs as targets. Multiple IPs can share the same URL as the target and the time an IP reaches a URL and leaves it for the next possible existing URL is also submitted in the timestamp column.

I would like to calculate the time an IP spends on each URL in the span of 30min. How can I do it?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.